# tipa package messes up compilation

Tags: errors, compiling, tipa

I am trying to use the `tipa` package to provide a different version of the Omega greek symbol:

```
\usepackage{tipa}
\newcommand{\scOmega}{\text{\textscomega}} % small omega*
```

But now I get that my entire document doesn't compile anymore as it's giving me errors of extra }:

```
./doc.tex:809: Argument of \bs has an extra }.
```

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{arydshln} % for cdashline

\usepackage{tipa}
\newcommand{\scOmega}{\text{\textscomega}} % small omega

\newcommand{\bs}[1] {\boldsymbol{#1}}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{align*}
\newcommand*{\tmp}{\multicolumn{1}{r|}{}} 
  \bs{K} & = \int_{0}^{x_\Gamma} EA \;  \bs{B} ^\intercal \bs{B}  \; \text{d}x + \int_{x_\Gamma}^{L} EA \; \bs{B} ^\intercal \bs{B}  \;  \text{d}x \\  
    & = \frac{EA}{L}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & \phantom{+}1 \\ \cdashline{1-3}
 -1 & \phantom{+}1 & -1 \\ 
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad \text{~and~} \bs{F} = \begin{bmatrix} R \\ \cdashline{1-2} P \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The relevant error is not this one, but the LaTeX warning before: `Command \; invalid in math mode`.  `tipa` apparently redefines `\;` which messes up the stuff following it.

Comment: But `\;` is a valid LaTeX command for a space, and my entire document has these. Can I fix this somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is misleading as it only asks about an error not raised by the example, but the error is that `tipa` redefines `\;` If you do not need the tipa definition you can restore the original version as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{arydshln} % for cdashline


\let\savedsemi\;
\usepackage{tipa}
\let\;\savedsemi
\newcommand{\scOmega}{\text{\textscomega}} % small omega

\newcommand{\bs}[1] {\boldsymbol{#1}}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{align*}
\newcommand*{\tmp}{\multicolumn{1}{r|}{}} 
  \bs{K} & = \int_{0}^{x_\Gamma} EA \;  \bs{B} ^\intercal \bs{B}  \; \text{d}x + \int_{x_\Gamma}^{L} EA \; \bs{B} ^\intercal \bs{B}  \;  \text{d}x \\  
    & = \frac{EA}{L}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & \phantom{+}1 \\ \cdashline{1-3}
 -1 & \phantom{+}1 & -1 \\ 
 \phantom{+}1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad \text{~and~} \bs{F} = \begin{bmatrix} R \\ \cdashline{1-2} P \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
}

\end{document}
```

The above is a general method of resolving package clashes, but for the specific case of tipa's redefinition of the standard math commands a more specific solution is available.

```
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
```

with the `safe` option the package avoids defining commands that clash with standard definitions.

Comment: I have the same problem with `\:`. Can I generalize this to many commands? Or better, can I just take a single command from `tipa`? The only thing I need is the `\textscomega`.

Comment: @aaragon looking at the comments in the file use `[safe]` option to tipa and it will not redefine the math commands

Comment: That worked! Could you please modify your answer so I mark it as solved?

Comment: @aaragon done..

Comment: Thank you so much! Have had problems with \iff operator. Apparently it was caused by tipa package and your suggestion fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

The manual of `tipa` specifies that you should use the `safe` option in order not to modify commands such as `\;` and `\!`. However, you're abusing them.

I made other fixes. You can't use `bmatrix` along with `\cdashline` and you need `array`. Also, loading `bm` is preferable for bold math symbols. Note that `\text{d}` is not guaranteed to make the `d` upright; I added a suitable definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{arydshln} % for cdashline

\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\newcommand{\scOmega}{\textnormal{\textscomega}} % small omega

\newcommand{\bs}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\bs{K}\;
& = \int_{0}^{x_\Gamma} EA \bs{B}^\intercal \bs{B} \diff x 
    + \int_{x_\Gamma}^{L} EA \bs{B}^\intercal \bs{B}  \diff x \\  
& = \frac{EA}{L}
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr@{}}
     1 & -1 &  1 \\ \cdashline{1-3}
    -1 &  1 & -1 \\ 
     1 & -1 &  1 \\
    \end{array}\right],
    \qquad \text{ and } 
    \bs{F} = 
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    R \\ \cdashline{1-1}
    P \\
    0
    \end{array}\right],
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want an additional space between `EA` and `\bs{B}`, use `\,` and not `\;`.

By the way, you don't need `tipa` to print a smaller Omega.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\scGreek}[1]{%
  \text{%
    \fontsize{0.7\dimexpr\f@size pt}{0}\selectfont
    $\m@th#1$%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\scOmega}{{\scGreek{\Omega}}}

\begin{document}

$x\Omega\neq x\scOmega_{\Omega+\scOmega}$

\end{document}
```

The code uses `\text` for automatically getting scalable symbols in superscripts and subscripts. The overall scale factor is 0.7, change it to suit you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are only after the Omega symbol, you can just add this symbol instead of the whole package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T3,OT1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\textscomega{T3}
\newcommand{\scOmega}{\text{\textscomega}} % small omega
\begin{document}

$\scOmega\Omega$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should probably be `\textnormal` instead of `\text`: if the symbol appears in an italic context, such as a theorem statement, it would be typeset in italic as well.